# Patching away function call before importing?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

If I'm importing from a module and want to prevent a function call from being ran in it, how can achieve that? For example...

sandbox.py

```
def foo():
    print("doing something I don't want to happen during testing like making a connection")
    ....

x = foo()

def get_num():
    return 1
```

test_sandbox.py

```
from sandbox import get_num

def get_num():
    assert get_num() == 1
```

I don't really care about foo or x, just want a way to make it so foo is not called when test_sandbox.py makes the import up top. In this current state, I will end up running foo.

How do I mock or patch to prevent foo from running during the import?

Comment: Mocking can't do that.

Comment: Ah right think I need to patch...

Comment: Still can't do that.

Comment: I also think mock can't do this.

But do you really have to write code that way?

I'd change the implementation such, that x is calculated only the first time it is needed and not already during import

There's many reasons to try to execute as little code during import as possible even if code looks a little clunkier or eve if you have a function like `get_x`
Which fetches x first time and stores it in a global for further calls.

Sometimes I change my own modules to simplify testing mocking in such ways.

Comment: The motivation behind this is I'm testing something that imports module x. Module x has has a global variable set to initializing a client makes some kind of connection. Module x is not mine... but I am using it. So just trying to just stop that connection without actually modifying module x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `monkeypatch` however, you need to know *what* `foo` is calling in order to patch it before importing. Taking your example we can illustrate how this would work.

```
import io
import sys


def test_get_num(monkeypatch):
    stdout = io.StringIO()

    with monkeypatch.context() as mc:
        mc.setattr(sys, 'stdout', stdout)
        from sandbox import get_num

        assert stdout.getvalue() == "doing something I don't want to happen during testing like making a connection\n"
        assert get_num() == 1
```

And then when we run it:

```
$ -> pytest -s test_sandbox.py 
========================= test session starts =========================================
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                         

test_sandbox.py .
```

Notice how even running `pytest` with `-s` to allow `print` statements to be shown in the console don't appear. You can do the same with `foo` in your real world example. If it is creating some database connection, then `monkeypatch` the connection to do nothing and *then* import after that. Hope that helps.